# Tobler's Hiking Function

Tags: cost-path

I am trying to use the tobler's hiking function to estimate the distance/time from an origin to destination points. The contour interval is 500 but I do not know how to interpret the results. Does it mean that the distance between each of the contour line is 1 hour because I used aniso_hr1 and where does the contour interval come in the interpretation?[image]

Comment: which program do you use to make this ?

Comment: @RoVo ArcGIS 10.3

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Comment: Even though I think that you have actually followed a good online source (made by N. Tripchevic) which describes how to implement Tobler's hiking function in ArcGis, I concur with @Vince about the fact that you should provide more details and some more context in order for people here to help you.

Comment: @Vince  The point on the map (Santa Ana Cave) is the origin point used for the analysis but the destination points are not included in the map (apologies) but the contour lines were extracted from the full analysis of the Tobler's function. I chose a contour interval of 500 which means the distance between a contour line and the successive one is 500. However, since I am trying to get d time from the origin point to the destination points, how am I expected to use the contour rings to achieve this? Is the distance between the rings 1hour since I used 60 mins during the analysis?

Comment: Please take the [Tour]. It explains that your job as original poster (OP) is to curate a quality Question. Neither of your comments on the question belong there. Instead the information they represent belongs within the body of the question. As stated by the Tour, there should be only one question per Question. It is not inappropriate to include the exact coordinate system in use and the exact command used to generate the results presented in the screenshot.